# Visual Basic - Gráficas Chart no muestra valores

Tags: vb.net, charts

```
     Private Sub dia()

    Dim minDate As New DateTime(fecha.Year, fecha.Month, fecha.Day, fecha.Hour - 1, fecha.Minute, fecha.Second)
    Dim maxDate As New DateTime(fecha.Year, fecha.Month, fecha.Day, fecha.Hour, fecha.Minute, fecha.Second)
    'querystring = "select Fecha,Temperatura from TempCam1 where fecha between'" + minDate + "' AND '" + maxDate + "'"
    querystring = "select Fecha,Temperatura from TempCam1"
    Dim Comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(querystring, conex)
    reader = Comm.ExecuteReader()
    grafTemp.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    grafTemp.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    grafTemp.Series(0).XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime
    grafTemp.Series(0).YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32
    grafTemp.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MM HH:mm"
    grafTemp.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = minDate.ToOADate()
    grafTemp.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = maxDate.ToOADate()


    While reader.Read
        grafTemp.Series(0).Points.AddY(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Temperatura")))
    End While
End Sub
```

Resulta que me he fijado que si comento las lineas AxisX.Minimum y AxisX.Maximun no me muestra la línea que recorre el gráfico, mostradome así las variaciones de la temperatura. Os Adjunto un trozo del código y sus respectivas capturas de pantalla.

[image: <b>Imagen sin comentar las líneas</b>]

[image: <b>Imagen con comentarios en el axisXMinimun y el axisXMaximun</b>]

Comment: Esto es vb.net no es vba.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, al llevar poco programando en este lenguaje, no sabía como etiquetarlo. Muchas gracias ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado con estás líneas de código que me faltaban por ponerle al proyecto

```
  Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(querystring, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "TempCam1")
    grafTemp.DataSource = ds.Tables("TempCam1")
```

Línea 1-3: Se ejecuta la consulta y se completa el resultado en el objeto DataSet.

Línea 4: Establece el origen de datos del gráfico en la tabla de datos en el objeto del conjunto de datos.